# Python dictionary of functions calls every function

Tags: python, dictionary

This seems very trivial but for some reason my dictionary is not working.

This is the code I have:

```
class Calculator():
    def __init__(self):
        number = input()
        self.switch_case(number)

    def switch_case(self, number):
        switcher = {
            1: self.one(),
            2: self.two(),
        }

    def one(self):
        print("something")

    def two(self):
        print("something")
```

For some reason this calls both functions one() and two() even when I only enter the value 1 as an input.

Comment: because both methods are explicitly called while creating the dictionary in `switch_case`

Comment: Can you make the title a bit more descriptive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it calls nothing. Your code as presented is never run.

But if you would create a `Calculator` instance, `__init__` is run which then runs `switch_case` and initializes the dictionary by evaluating the value expressions. This will call both functions.

If you don't want to run them at this point, remove the parentheses:

```
switcher = {
        1: self.one,
        2: self.two,
        }
```

and call the function when needed, with something like:

```
self.switcher[1]()
```

Note the `()` which will do the call.

Comment: Thanks, but why do we need the 'self' in self.swicther[1]()

Comment: If you use it inside the method `switch_case` only, then you don't need it. If you want to use the dictionary somewhere else you have to attach it to `self`.

Answer (score 1):

When you create dictionary, first these methods are called = thats why you see *something* twice, then values which are returned from methods are assigned to dict (in this case None, cause methods only prints, nothing returned).